# How to edit colnames in R?

Tags: regex, r

I have variable called **name**, I want to set it as column names of my matrix, but before doing this, I need to edit names inside of my variable called **name**

```
>name
[722] "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A-12R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt"
[723] "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A-11R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt"
[724] "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A-11R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt"
```

I want just keep the letters before the fourth **`-`**

Expected Output:

```
  >name
    [722] "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A"
    [723] "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A"
    [724] "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A"
```

would someone help me to implement this in R ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the size varies/not guaranteed `nchar` away you can use `str_split_fixed()` from `stringr`.

#### `stringr` solution:

```
library(stringr)

name <- c(
    "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A-12R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt",
    "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A-11R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt",
    "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A-11R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt")

apply(str_split_fixed(name,"-",5)[,1:4],1,paste0,collapse="-")
```

will give you what you:

```
## "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A"
```

#### explanation:

- `str_split_fixed(name,"-",5)`

*split each vector element of `name` into `5` pieces according to the first 5 ocurences of `-`*

- `[,1:4]`

*retain the first 4 pieces (columns of resulting matrix) for each `name` element*

- `apply(...,1,paste0,collapse="-")`

*paste them together collapsing using the `"-"` to restore the names (rowwise)*

---

### but what if i have many many names?

Here I'm comparing my `stringr`+`apply()` method to @BondedDust `grep` method and the basic `strsplit` method.

First, let's bump it up to a 10 thousand names:

```
name <- rep(name,3.334e3)
```

then a microbenchmark:

```
microbenchmark(
  stringr_apply = apply(str_split_fixed(name,"-",5)[,1:4],1,paste0,collapse="-"),
  grep_ninja = sub("^([^-]*[-][^-]*[-][^-]*[-][^-]*)([-].*$)", "\\1", name),
  strsplit = sapply( lapply( strsplit(name, "\\-"), "[", 1:4), paste, collapse="-"), 
  times=25)
```

and get:

```
#  Unit: milliseconds
#  expr             min       lq    median        uq       max    neval
# stringr_apply 845.44542 874.5674 899.27849 941.22628 976.88903    25
# grep_ninja     25.51796  25.7066  25.85404  25.95922  27.89165    25
# strsplit      115.10626 123.2645 126.45171 130.10334 147.39517    25
```

seems like `base` pattern matching / replacement will scale better...about a second here or 30x faster than the slowest way.

Comment: Looks pretty slow and complex and requires extra package. `strsplit` might have been easier to illustrate if you didn't want to use regex methods.

Comment: @BondedDust I very much agree after seeing your answer (hence upvote). I wanted to see if it scaled -- edited answer to add little benchmark. and it's exactly as suspected. thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: Thanks. The `strsplit` approach also beat the `str_split` by a factor of 5.

Answer (score 8):

The regex "[" operator defines a character class and in the character class the "^" operator in the first position does negation;

```
?regex
?sub

sub("^([^-]*[-][^-]*[-][^-]*[-][^-]*)([-].*$)", "\\1", name)
[1] "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A"
```

This would be simpler (IMO)  than the  str_split approach

```
 sapply( lapply( strsplit(name, "\\-"), "[", 1:4),   
                # extracted the first 4 elements from each list element returned by strsplit
         paste, collapse="-")  # 'collapse' needed rather than 'sep'

#[1] "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A"
```

Comment: Nice. Also, you could use `([^-]*[-]){3}` to represent three repetitions of that sub-pattern, as in: `sub("^(([^-]*[-]){3}[^-]*)([-].*$)", "\\1", name)`

Comment: `strsplit` is the  way I'd go.  Sometimes speed isn't as important as accuracy, but this has both.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want `substr` :

```
names <- substr(names,start=1,stop=16)
colnames(myDF) <- names
```

This overwrites the original `names` with the substring you specified. Where `names` is your names variable, `start` is the first character, and `stop` the last character. You then overwrite the colnames of your data.frame or whatever with the `names`.

Comment: what is myname ? could you ve more explicite ?

Answer (score 1):

Another option with the `stringr` package (though still much slower than @BondedDust's answer):

```
library('stringr')
str_match(name, "^([^-]*[-][^-]*[-][^-]*[-][^-]*)")[, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of the fifth set of alphanumerics end with `R`,

```
> txt <- c("TCGA-OL-A66N-01A-12R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt",
           "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A-11R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt",
           "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A-11R-A31S-13.isoform.quantification.txt")

> gsub("-[0-9]{2}R.*", "", txt)
# [1] "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A"
```

or if the same chunk always starts with `1`, but doesn't end in `R`.

```
> gsub("-[1-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}.*", "", txt)
```

You can also use a regular expression in `strsplit`, which I didn't see much of in the other responses.

```
> unlist(strsplit(txt, "-[1-9]{2}[A-Z].*"))
# [1] "TCGA-OL-A66N-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66O-01A" "TCGA-OL-A66P-01A"
```

I look for a nice pattern to avoid writing an excessively long, confusing regular expression.